# How to detect latin1 and UTF-8?

Tags: perl, unicode, encoding, utf-8, latin1

I am extracting strings from an XML file, and even though it should be pure UTF-8, it is not. My idea was to

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Encode qw(decode encode);
use Data::Dumper;

my $x = "m\x{e6}gtig";
my $y = "m\x{c3}\x{a6}gtig";

my $a = encode('UTF-8', $x);
my $b = encode('UTF-8', $y);

print Dumper $x;
print Dumper $y;
print Dumper $a;
print Dumper $b;

if ($x eq $y) { print "1\n"; }
if ($x eq $a) { print "2\n"; }
if ($a eq $y) { print "3\n"; }
if ($a eq $b) { print "4\n"; }
if ($x eq $b) { print "5\n"; }
if ($y eq $b) { print "6\n"; }
```

outputs

```
$VAR1 = 'm�gtig';
$VAR1 = 'mægtig';
$VAR1 = 'mægtig';
$VAR1 = 'mÃ¦gtig';
3
```

under the idea that only a latin1 string would increase its length, but encoding an already UTF-8 also makes it longer. So I can't detect latin1 vs UTF-8 that way.

**Question**

I would like to end up with always UTF-8 string, but how can I detect if it is latin1 or UTF-8, so I only convert the latin1 string?

Being able to get a yes/no if a string is UTF-8 would be just as useful.

Comment: Do you want a solution to guess what´s the correct charset or do you want something accurate? Bacause, latter is not possible.

Comment: If it is not possible to do it accurately, then guessing it better than nothing =)

Comment: @deviantfan, Guessing is very accurate. See the footnote in my answer.

Comment: @ikegami: It´s still guessing. I´m not saying this is bad, but that won´t change the fact.

Comment: @deviantfan, You seem to have misread something. I never said it wasn't guessing.

Comment: @ikegami: I´m not pretending anything? I didn´t meant it in any bad way, if you understood it so.

Comment: Can't you avoid all this by going back to whoever is supplying you with this data and asking them to provide valid UTF8?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Due to some properties of UTF-8, it's very unlikely that text encoded using iso-8859-1 would be valid UTF-8 unless it decodes identically using both encodings<sup>[1]</sup>.

As such, the solution is to try decoding it using UTF-8. If it fails, decode it using iso-8859-1 instead. Since decoding using iso-8859-1 is a no-op, I'll be skipping that step.

- utf8:: implementation:

  ```
  my $decoded_text = $utf8_or_latin1;
  utf8::decode($decoded_text);
  ```
- Encode:: implementation:

  ```
  use Encode qw( decode_utf8 );

  my $decoded_text =
     eval { decode_utf8($utf8_or_latin1, Encode::FB_CROAK|Encode::LEAVE_SRC) }
        // $utf8_or_latin1;
  ```

---

Now, you say you want UTF-8. UTF-8 is obtained from encoding decoded text.

- utf8:: implementation:

  ```
  my $utf8 = $decoded_text;
  utf8::encode($utf8);
  ```
- Encode:: implementation:

  ```
  use Encode qw( encode_utf8 );

  my $utf8 = encode_utf8($decoded_text);
  ```

---

Notes

1. Assuming the text is either valid UTF-8 or valid iso-8859-1, my solution would only guess wrong if all of the following are true:

   - The text is encoded using iso-8859-1 (as opposed to UTF-8),
   - At least one of [
     <80><81><82><83><84><85><86><87><88><89><8A><8B><8C><8D><8E><8F>
     <90><91><92><93><94><95><96><97><98><99><9A><9B><9C><9D><9E><9F>
     <NBSP>¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬<SHY>®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿
     ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞß
     àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷
     ] is present,
   - All instances of [ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞß] are followed by one of [
     <80><81><82><83><84><85><86><87><88><89><8A><8B><8C><8D><8E><8F>
     <90><91><92><93><94><95><96><97><98><99><9A><9B><9C><9D><9E><9F>
     <NBSP>¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬<SHY>®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿],
   - All instances of [àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîï] are followed by two of [
     <80><81><82><83><84><85><86><87><88><89><8A><8B><8C><8D><8E><8F>
     <90><91><92><93><94><95><96><97><98><99><9A><9B><9C><9D><9E><9F>
     <NBSP>¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬<SHY>®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿],
   - All instances of [ðñòóôõö÷] are followed by three of [
     <80><81><82><83><84><85><86><87><88><89><8A><8B><8C><8D><8E><8F>
     <90><91><92><93><94><95><96><97><98><99><9A><9B><9C><9D><9E><9F>
     <NBSP>¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬<SHY>®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿],
   - None of [øùúûüýþÿ] are present, and
   - None of [
     <80><81><82><83><84><85><86><87><88><89><8A><8B><8C><8D><8E><8F>
     <90><91><92><93><94><95><96><97><98><99><9A><9B><9C><9D><9E><9F>
     <NBSP>¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬<SHY>®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿
     ] are present except where previously mentioned.

   (<80>..<9F> are unassigned or unprintable control characters, not sure which.)

   In other words, that code is very reliable.

Comment: How come encoding utf8 to utf8 doesn't trash it? It does in my OP.

Comment: In your example it works, which i don't understand why it does, as it fails in my.

Comment: I don't encode UTF-8 bytes using UTF-8. I don't encode UTF-8 bytes, period. I encode decoded text (Unicode code points) using UTF-8.

Comment: @ikegami, hi, could you please elaborate on why decoding using iso-8859-1 is a no-op? Why not simply add the following to you Encode:: implementation: `my $decoded_text = eval { ... } // decode ("iso-8859-1", $utf8_or_latin1);`? Thanks

Comment: @n.r. Re "*why decoding using iso-8859-1 is a no-op?*", Because Unicode is an extension of iso-8851-1. Specifically, iso-8859-1 0 is Code Point 0, 1 is 1, 2 is 2, ..., and FF is FF.